# How to remove salt&pepper noise in MatLab

Tags: image, matlab, mask, noise

Hi I need to remove the salt&pepper noise from an image. My function has 3 parameters input_img_path, a mask(i j)==1 and output_img_path. I need someone to explain how does that mask work and how to remove that noise.

Comment: Did you just ask us to do your homework for you?

Comment: I don't understand that mask function. I'm not asking you to do my homework. I just don't understand this function

Comment: either it's part of one of the matlab components, in which case it's in the documentation (like Simulink), or it's a custom function, in which case you should just look at what its function definition says. Based on nothing, because you didn't actually show any relevant code, I'm going with "it acts as Kronecker delta function"

Answer (score 1):

Noise filtering

use your recorded voice in ‘ wavread’ command……

this is how i remove the noise from audio, try it on images by yourself.. use this medfilt2 to remove noise from images.. hope it'll work fine for u.
`[y,Fs]=wavread('C:\Users\user\Downloads\bugsbunny1.wav');
Y=imnoise(y,'salt & pepper',0.02);
K= medfilt2(Y,[5 1])
wavplay(K)`